# Incrementing a for loop upward in C

Tags: python, c, loops

I am hoping to mimic a Python for loop with the range() function in C. I'd like to accomplish a task an increasing number of times each loop until I reach the value of a given variable, in this case 5 (for the variable h). Here it is in Python:

```
x = 5
y = 0
while x > y:
    for i in range(y+1):
        print("@",end='') 
    print('')
    y+=1

Output: 
@
@@
@@@
@@@@
@@@@@
```

I was able to accomplish the opposite (executing something a decreasing number of times) in C, as below:

```
{
    int h = 5;
    
    while (h > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
        {
            printf("@");
        }
        printf("\n");
        h--;
    }
}

Output:
@@@@@
@@@@
@@@
@@
@
```

When I've attempted the top version in C, with the increasing number of executions, I run into the problem of not knowing how to control the various incrementing and decrementing variables.

Comment: What specifically is it about the `range()` function in Python that you are hoping to mimic?

Comment: Well, your python uses two variables, x and y, to control the loops, but your C version only uses one, h. And it decreases a counter instead of increasing. Start with making it use the same logic as the python version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you should think simply:

1. Increment up the number of `@` to print
2. Use loop to print that number of `@`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int h = 5;
    
    for (int c = 1; c <= h; c++) // the number of @ to print
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
        {
            printf("@");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Another way is simply writing in just the same way as the Python version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x = 5;
    int y = 0;

    while (x > y)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < y+1; i++)
        {
            printf("@");
        }
        printf("\n");
        y += 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int x = 5;
    int y = 0;
    while (x > y)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<y+1;i++)
        {
            printf("@");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In Python, in the for loop, the variable is initialized as zero and increments by 1 by default. But in C, you need to do it explicitly.